# What is contained in int.class in Java ?Why is it even valid?

Tags: java

In Java it is valid to have a class literal for primitives like `int.class`. Was this allowed even prior to the introduction of `auto boxing` feature in Java ? What does the object that we get out of  `int.class` contain actually ? Why is it valid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is not a class, so `int.class` doesn't really make sense.

The reason is they went cheap, and used one `Class` to represent all *types*. So for example, `Method.getReturnType()` returns a `Class`, which could actually represent a class, or a primitive, an array, or even void.

That was sort of fine, before generics, since there weren't too many kinds of types. After generics, things get really messy, the new `Type` hierarchy makes even less sense, since it incorporates the old messy `Class`; as a result the tree of `Types` looks nothing like the tree of types in the language spec.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is a key part of reflection (e.g. describing a method which takes an `int` parameter).  there is a `Void` class as well.